# Why does Green's function for wave equation in one spatial dimension have no singularity?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, wave-equation, greens-function

[image]

Green's function is the response to a Dirac-delta source. But the green's function for wave equation in one spatial dimension doesn't seem to have a singularity, whereas the heat equation does. What's the reason for this?

Comment: For some derivative operator $L$, schematically we have $LG=\delta$. It is the *derivatives* of $G$ that must produce the delta on the RHS, not $G$ itself

Comment: I believe the singularity you are referring to is that of the diagonal matrix element of $G$, namely, $G(0,0)$. Remember that small distances correspond to _large_ $k$ values in Fourier space, and that $G$ in Fourier space goes like $1/k^2$ for the wave equation. This is integrable in 1D (but not higher) which is why it is not singular in 1D.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, short of actually calculating the [Greens functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function), [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) can give a crude hint/inside of what singularities to expect although it fails to detect e.g. logarithmic singularities, and cannot distinguish between e.g. $1/x$ and $\delta(x)$.

*Examples:*

1. Dimensional analysis of the $n$-dimensional [Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) $-\vec{\nabla}^2 G(\vec{r})~=~\delta^n(\vec{r})$ suggests that $G(\vec{r})~\sim~r^{2-n} $. In OP's 3rd picture with $n=2$ this is constant, i.e. it failed to detect a logarithmic singularity.
2. Dimensional analysis of the $(n+1)$-dimensional [d'Alembertian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator)/[wave operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) $(\partial_t^2-\vec{\nabla}^2)G(\vec{r},t)~=~\delta^{n}(\vec{r})\delta(t)$ suggests that $G(\vec{r},t)~\sim~(r^2-t^2)^{(1-n)/2} $.
   In OP's 1st picture with $n=1$ this correctly predicts no singularity.
3. Dimensional analysis of the $n$-dimensional [heat operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) $(\partial_t-\vec{\nabla}^2)G(\vec{r},t)~=~\delta^{n}(\vec{r})\delta(t)$ suggests that $G(\vec{r},t)~\sim~t^{-n/2} $. In OP's 2nd picture with $n=1$ this correctly predicts a singularity.

Of course this answer is an oversimplication of the actual singularity structure, and is only meant as a tool to develop some intuition.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Qmechanic's good points, we can also think in terms of (e.g., $L^2$) Sobolev spaces, as characterized by the weighted $L^2$ spaces the Fourier transforms lie in. Thus, considering $\Delta u=\delta$, we have (up to normalization) $-r^2\widehat{u}=\widehat{\delta}=1$. It is elementary that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} 1\cdot (1+|x|^2)^{-{n\over 2}-\epsilon}\,dx<+\infty$, so $\delta\in H^{-{n\over 2}-\epsilon}(\mathbb R^n)$, for every $\epsilon>0$. Since $-\Delta$ is a "positive" second order operator, it shifts the Sobolev space index by $2$. Thus, a fundamental solution is in $H^{-{n\over 2}+2-\epsilon}(\mathbb R^n)$.

At the same time, Sobolev's imbedding/inequality shows that on $\mathbb R^n$ it is essentially sharp that $H^{{n\over 2}+\epsilon}(\mathbb R^n)\subset C^o(\mathbb R^n)$.

So, the fundamental solution is continuous *if* (let's not quite say "only if") $-{n\over 2}+2-\epsilon > {n\over 2}$ for some small-enough $\epsilon>0$. This is equivalent to $2-\epsilon>n$, so only $n=1$ can succeed.